# Google Tag manager , DataLayer pushes event without variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

I have this piece of a code:

```js
dataLayer.push({
    'virtualPageviewType': 'Gallery',
    'virtualPageURL': window.location.href,
    'virtualPageTitle': $('article.h1').text(),
    'event': 'VirtualPageview'
});
```

And using GTM debug mode I see trigger is working, tag as well. I can fetch proper event in GTM and I see it in GA.

I can't however, access `virtualPageviewType` variable. It doesn't even show up in debugger (other two variables do show up). I just recently added this variable to the script and GTM, purged all caches so I'm sure it's not the case. I see proper .js file in the browser, updated and all.

But still, GTM debugger can't see `virtualPageviewType` variable and sets it to default (empty string). In GA it shows as `(direct)` - I wanted to transfer `virtualPageviewType` variable into `campaignSource` field.

What can be the reason behind this behavior? What is the solution? Please help.

Comment: Are you able to see the other variables?

Comment: @AndrésAndrade They show up in the GTM Debugger so I guess yes. I don't really use them in GTM itself, as I use build-in variables instead